# Created nested tables, need horizontal spacing or side-by-side layout for tracking dates and weights

Tags: google-docs

I made a 1x2 table, placed a 10x2 table in each cell, and removed the parent table's borders.

[image]

I aim for space between the tables. Line spacing added vertical, not horizontal space.
Is there another method to create symmetrical, side-by-side 10x2 or 20x2 tables?
I'm exploring better online tools for this task.
The goal is a printable sheet to track two people's dates and weights.

Comment: If your goal is to create a paper form, I think that you should add the full specification of the page to be printed, like pager size, margins, page header / footer, text above and below the table, cell sizes in cm or inches, etc. Mention that you are stuck on formatting the table using Google Docs. If you are open to using other apps, like but not limited to Google Sheets or Google Slides, mention that you are looking for a free software application that is compatible with your operative system, mention name and version.

Comment: If the scope of this question is limited to handling tables in Google Docs, then the question is off-topic in Super User. It might be on topic in Web Applicatications SE, but it still needs more details. If it will be migrated, I suggest to add the missing details before migrating it.